# How to delete lines in a non delimited file in unix

Tags: unix, grep, nawk, awk

I want to delete lines based on "CLIENT TOTAL" and the succeeding unit lines untill next name.
The number of unit lines(i.e lines with 30.0 and 15.0) after "CLIENT TOTAL" line may vary untill the next name.
Most importantly the file is not delimited.
Given below is my input file.
INPUT:

```
RELATIVITY/O F   32629 DT MBSA  
HALL             15.0             5,850
HALL             30.0            21,650
RELATIVITY/O F   34145 DT MBSA  
HALL             30.0            10,850
*CLIENT TOTAL RELATIVITY/O F     38,350
                 30.0            32,500
                 15.0             5,850
PFIZER           96607 DT MBSA  
HALL             15.0            32,700
HALL             30.0            21,300
PFIZER           96609 DT MBSA  
HALL             60.0            30,200
HALL             75.0           182,100
HALL             90.0            67,700
*CLIENT TOTAL PFIZER            334,000
                 90.0            67,700
                 30.0            21,300
                 15.0            32,700
```

I want my output as below.
OUTPUT:

```
RELATIVITY/O F   32629 DT MBSA  
HALL             15.0             5,850
HALL             30.0            21,650
RELATIVITY/O F   34145 DT MBSA  
HALL             30.0            10,850
PFIZER           96607 DT MBSA  
HALL             15.0            32,700
HALL             30.0            21,300
PFIZER           96609 DT MBSA  
HALL             60.0            30,200
HALL             75.0           182,100
HALL             90.0            67,700
```

Comment: `grep -v '^[* ]' file`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
awk '/CLIENT TOTAL/||/^[[:space:]]/{next}1' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk '
  # If line contains "CLIENT TOTAL" or starts with whitespace, skip it
  /CLIENT TOTAL/ || /^[[:space:]]/ { next }
  # Otherwise, print it
  1
' file
```

Comment: I would have used this `awk '/CLIENT TOTAL/||/^[^[:alnum:]]/ {next}1'` to take care of space and tabs.  (you do not need the `;` before 1`